# How to select a radiobutton in Dynamics AX (by code)?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

What is the code to pre-select a radioButton-item?

Comment: you don't really unselect radio buttons, one in the group needs to be selected...

Comment: How can I do this in X++? Thank you.

Comment: Ok I want to select an invisible item is this possible?

Comment: why would you do this? I think you need a check box or a drop down, but I have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: When I open my dropDialog the first item is selected, I don't want this.

Comment: you have a drop dialog now? I think the best idea here is for you to add more information to the question so someone can answer it

Comment: What I need at the moment is only the code to select a radioButton, that's it. I've updated the question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method `RadioButton.selection(i)`, where `i` is your 0 based array index for your radio buttons.

You may need to set the radio button property "Auto declaration" to true to access the selection method.

Comment: I can't put this code in init method of the DropDialog, right?

Comment: the radioButton is part of the dropDialog. I have overriden the init-method of the dropDialog. And I've put the code you provided in the init-method. And I get FormRadioControl object not initialized.